# After GKE master upgrade, outgoing traffic on IPSec tunnel comes from pod IP range instead of node IP range

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

A peculiar issue just hit us after upgrading the master on one of our GKE clusters.

We have, in the same network, a bunch of IPSec tunnels set up. Before, the IPs of outgoing requests would be in the 10.164.0.0/16 range - which is the IP range of the nodes.

After the update, all outgoing traffic is suddenly in the 10.56.0.0/14 range, which is the IP range of our pods.

Since several external suppliers have their firewalls set up for specifically 10.164.0.0/16, this is extremely disruptive.

Is there any way to revert this back to using node IPs for outgoing traffic, instead of pod IPs?

Comment: Could you share more information? From what version to what version you have upgraded your cluster? Did you use any Ingress? Did you do something more than upgrading master?  Did you configure `IP masquerade` or `reserve static IP` on GKE before?

Comment: @PjoterS
The upgrade was for both the master and the nodes from 1.14.x to 1.15.x (cannot remember the exact versions). I looked into the masquerade thing and that turns out to have been it - for some reason, either the default behaviour changed between 1.14 and 1.15, or the ip-masq-agent went from being installed to not being installed. After (re?)installing the ip-masq-agent and configuring it to omit the remote IP range, everything went back to normal. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this thanks to the remark left in the first comment on my question.

It turned out that between 1.14 and 1.15, either the default behaviour of ip-masq-agent changed, or the whole thing was uninstalled.

After installing and configuring ip-masq-agent according to this site - https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent - everything went back to normal.

Specifically, I had to take the default config and omit the one IP range that was problematic on the other end of the IPSec tunnel.